# How to create deb packages of Monodevelop application for Ubuntu

Tags: c#, ubuntu, monodevelop, packaging, gtk#

I have created a project in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS that is written in C# using MonoDevelop. I've been trying for some time now to get my head around linux packaging, but I keep coming away feeling frustrated and overwhelmed.

My program consists of:

A main project ("MyProgramName") that just starts the Desktop application.

What (I think) I want to do is really very simple (I think):

Compile my application

Copy the .exe and .dll files (to /usr/local/bin?)

Oh, and I want to do this as a .deb package. I think if I can get the tarball working, a .deb package shouldn't be too much trouble, but that's what I want to do eventually.

I'm still not really sure how to do this. I've used MonoDevelop to create a Tarball. When I install the tarball (using
./configure
,
make
,
sudo make install
), it copies all dll files from my /bin directory to  (/usr/local/bin?), but it skips the main .exe file. As a result not create a command to run the program.

How would I go about doing this? Sorry if this is a basic/broad question. I've been googling around about this, and I can't seem to find anything that doesn't assume I know the basics of packaging (even if it claims it doesn't assume this). Please explain this concept i.e. create deb package of monodevelop application, I am just begginer in Mono Development.